# Flash JW Player - scroll loaded video to ot loaded position

Tags: video, jwplayer, flash

I decided to test JW Player player.
And I saw a very unpleasant feature of JW Player player. For example, I have a weak internet connection, and the video is very large. If at a certain time player had downloaded (cached) only 20% of the video, I can not rewind the video to the position, assume 73%. When you try to rewind the video to the position to which the file has not been downloaded (cached), resets the player to the beginning the video.
In the current setup I have played flv file.

Does JW Player player can scroll the video to a point that has not yet been downloaded (cached) by JW Player? I need to get JW Player player started to download videos from exactly the same position that the user needs, and not from the very beginning - to save bandwidth.

http://postimg.org/image/hpmmazj33/

Advise, please, flash video player, which would allow the video to scroll to the positions at the current time has not yet been loaded (cached).

Comment: The only player that I have seen that has a feature like this is Youtube, really. It is all set server side, though.

Comment: OK. I have implemented config with nginx pseudo streaming modules for flv and for H264 MP4. But I have some issues with JW Player in IE 11. In IE flv playing in JW Player with nginx +flv pseudostreaming modules is hangs after 2-5 seconds. With MP4 in JW Player with nginx +MP4 pseudostreaming there are no issues - JW Player played MP4 very good. Because FLV files hangs playing in JW Player, I have changed my choice to the FlowPlayer- it's correctly playing FLV and MP4 both.

Comment: Do you have a link to where the issues are happening?

Comment: No... Now it's on my localhost. Nginx in on CentOS 6.4 Virtual machine, whats located on my localmache, IE - on local machine. May be in future I can get you link, but now I has not dedicated server for demonstration.

Comment: Hm, I would need to see a link at this point to be able to debug properly.